# Google Analytics 4 User Purchase Journey Not Capturing Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, enhanced-ecommerce

My GA4 User Purchase Journey is not capturing events rather than only session start.

[image: Google Analytics 4 User Purchase Journey]

The GA4 Ecommerce purchases also not capturing any 'Items viewed' 'Items added to cart' events... in GA debugView it shows those view_item, add_to_cart, begin_checkout and purchase events real time... but it seems this enhanced ecommerce is not capturing or calculating any reports based on those... specifically items viewed and begin_checkout and added to cart event not capturing.

[image: GA4 Ecommerce Purchases]

These are my events and custom events in GA Admin events...

[image: GA Events]

[image: GA custom events]

These are my conversions

[image: GA conversions]

GTM Tag

[image: GTM Tag]

When I test debugView it's capturing events properly but not these events showing up in reports

[image: GA debugView]

I am new to this things please forgive my any errors... please suggest! thanks

Answer (score 1):

GA4 expects the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm) (or the [Custom JavaScript Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#use_a_custom_javascript_variable)) to adhere to the specific schema as described in mentioned docs. Otherwise the ecommerce reports would not show the relevant metrics (ie. `Items Viewed` under  **Moneitization > E-commerce purchases**) even though you can see the numbers under Events report just like in your [3rd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3yDi.png). These ecommerce events must adhere to the specified event names & should contain the `items` array.

You might find [this guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-analytics-4-ecommerce-guide-google-tag-manager/) by Simo Ahava helpful.

Comment: My schema is correct i can see in debug in tag manager...

`{
  event: "begin_checkout",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: 7, start: 1693238574684},
  ecommerce: {
    value: 28.88,
    currency: "USD",
    items: [
      {
        item_id: "PRODUCT_6512",
        item_name: "Oreganol P73 Gelcaps - 120 Gelcaps"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I just want to highlight __"should contain the `items` array"__ as being very important. In my case I was sending the events, but one of the events was missing the `items` array. That stopped all the following events from working. The `items` array must exist, and I suppose it must remain the same, throughout the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are skipping any events like view_product or add_to_cart then the stock Purchase Journey report is not going to work - you will need to create a custom one using only the events that you are actually sending.